I want to upgrade Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04 but I am not able to
I have tried sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, same things I did to upgrade Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 but I am not able to upgrade to 24.04 by same methods. I have even tried sudo apt dist-upgrade and  sudo apt do-release-upgrade. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong or any alternatives for upgrading to 24.04.

Upgrading from version 22.04 to 24.04 is currently bugged, and might cause your system to get bricked, if you must use 24.04, do a fresh install, or wait till things get a bit more stable.

Canonical don't wants you to upgrade from any version of ubuntu to 24.04 lts release; until 24.04.1 is released; because it has a lot of bugs; So, you need to wait until 15th of August.You see that topic in here. Picture of the Reason

I fresh installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and i saw these bugs.

and sorry about these mistakes in the text.

The phrasing of this answer seems inaccurate. The Ubuntu developers include both volunteers and Canonical engineers. It's a decision of an Ubuntu team, not a Canonical policy. Ubuntu routinely phases LTS releases into clean-install (April), upgrade from previous x.10 release (May), and upgrade from previous LTS (August) so that enough testing occurs on each path to ensure most folks get a good experience. "because it has a lot of bugs," while arguably true (most software has a lot of bugs) is misleading.

A screenshot of Google is better than no citation at all, so thank you for citing a source. A link to the source answer (which is also here on AskUbuntu) would be better. A quote (and link) showing the actual answer in the 24.04 Release Notes would be best.
